# How to automate code behind using SQL job?

Tags: sql, vb.net, clr

I have this VB code to delete junk files from my web server. The code seems to run fine and I want to automate this code to run it daily by using sql job. How can that be done?

Here is the code:

```
Public Sub GetFilesAndFolders()
    Dim dirInfo As DirectoryInfo = New DirectoryInfo(Server.MapPath("~/test"))
    Dim fileInfo() As FileInfo = dirInfo.GetFiles("*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
    Dim fileExist As ArrayList = New ArrayList()
    Dim pathExist As ArrayList = New ArrayList()
    Dim fileToDelete As ArrayList = New ArrayList()
    pathExist = returnPathExist()
    For Each d As FileInfo In fileInfo
        If String.Format("{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", d.CreationTime) = Date.Today Then
            fileExist.Add("~\test\" & d.Name)
        End If
    Next

    For Each listElement As String In fileExist
        If Not pathExist.Contains(listElement) Then
            fileToDelete.Add(listElement)
        End If
    Next

    For Each item As String In fileToDelete
        Dim imageFile As FileInfo = New FileInfo(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(item))
        If imageFile.Exists Then
            File.Delete(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(item))
        End If
    Next

End Sub

Function returnPathExist() As ArrayList
    Dim pathExist As ArrayList = New ArrayList()
    'declare connection to the database and stored procedure
    Try
        cnn.Open()
        rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader
        While rdr.Read()
            pathExist.Add(rdr("test"))

        End While
        rdr.Close()
    Finally
        cnn.Close()
        cnn.Dispose()
    End Try
    Return pathExist
End Function
```

I want to use CLR but not sure which CLR I should add. Module, class, stored procedure or ??? And CLR doesn't support httpcontext and system.Configuration.ConfigurationManager which I need to access my stored procedure in the returnPathExist function above.

Thanks for your advice.

Update:

I am just one step away from getting this to work. Here are the lines that throw error:

```
Dim dirInfo As DirectoryInfo = New DirectoryInfo(Server.MapPath("~/test"))

Dim imageFile As FileInfo = New FileInfo(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(item))

File.Delete(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(item))
```

It seems HttpContext.Current can't be used in CLR. Is it true? Any work around to fix this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should really have a configuration setting for the paths.  `HttpContext.Current` is only valid for an ASP.NET request/response context.

Comment: Thanks Daniel. I suspect so, but where can I configure the setting for the paths?

Comment: I see. So all the paths I store will have to be direct path, is it correct? For instance, if I have a file called test.txt, the path will have to be C://inetpub/..../test.txt. Thanks for your patience.